# Some doubts about the proof of the Structure theorem for finite soluble $T$-groups

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, proof-explanation

[image]

It is ok that $x$ must induce a power automorphism in $L_p$. Does it induce a power automorphism in $M_p/L_{p'}$ just because $M_p$ is fixed by $x$ by conjugation ($M(p)$ is normal in $G$) and $M(p)/L{p'}$ is abelian? The fact that it must be $m \not \equiv 1$ mod $p$ should follow by the fact that $x \in G/C(p)$ must have as order a divisor of $p'$ and hence, since $G/C(p) \to \mathrm{Paut}(L_p)$ is injective, then the power automorphism cannot have fixed point. Why it must be  $n \not \equiv 1$ mod $p$ even for the power automorphism in $M_p/L_{p'}$? Finally i don't understand the equality $M(p)=[M(p),x]L_{p'}=L_{p'}[M(p),x]$. Using the fact that conjugation by $x$ induces a power automorphism i get, for an element $a \in M(p)$, that $a^n \equiv xax^{-1}$ mod $L_{p'}$, i.e. $a^{n-1}=l_{p'}xax^{-1}a^{-1}$; but i don't think this is enough to show the equality. Probably it is trivial, but i can't see it now. Thanks to everybody.

Comment: The fact that $n \not \equiv 1$ mod $p$ should be true because $a^{n-m}=1$, since the restriction of the power automorphism in $M(p)/L{p'}$ to $L/L_{p'}$ sends $a \mapsto a^m$, hence $n \equiv m$ mod $p$.

Answer (score 1):

There is a result, which you are probably expected to know, that if a $p'$-automorphism of a $p$-group $P$ induces the identity on $P/\Phi(P)$, then it is the identity on $p$. So, since $x$ does not centralize $P := M(p)/L_{p'}$, it cannot induce the identity on $P/\Phi(P) = P/P^p$ and so, if it is a power automorphism $x \mapsto x^n$, then we must have $n \not\equiv 1 \bmod p$.

So we get $[x,P/\Phi(P)] = P/\Phi(P)$ and hence $[x,P]\Phi(P) = P$, so $[x,P]=P$.

I don't know why $x$ induces a power automorphism on $P$. Presumably that follows from earlier results, such as 13.4.3, which you have not stated.

Comment: Do you mean "induces the identity of $P$"? What do you mean with $p'$-automorphism?

Comment: Oh, maybe it means that it has order a power of $p'$.

Comment: A $p'$-automorphism is one whose order (as an element of ${\rm Aut}(P)$ is not divisible by $p$. You seem confused about $p'$; this is not a number, so "a power of $p'$" does not mean anything.

Comment: Oh, ok. What about $\Phi(P)$ what is it $\Phi$? I know that $L_{p'}$ should be the complement of $L_{p}$ in $L$, right?

Comment: $\Phi(P)$ is the Frattini subgroup of $P$.

Comment: That's right. I don't know why, i can't see the equality.

Comment: What equality? What step in the argument do you not understand?

Comment: The one in which you claim that $[x,P/\Phi(P)]=P/\Phi(P)$. I can only see that, because of the power automorphism, it holds $(P/\Phi(P))^n=P/\Phi(P)$.

Comment: If $n \equiv r \bmod p$, then $[x,y\Phi(P)] = y^{1-r}\Phi(P)$ for all $y \in P$, and the elements $y^{1-r}\Phi(P)$ generate $P/\Phi(P)$ when $r \ne 1$.

Comment: Ok, got it! Just use the structure for finite abelian $p$-groups. Thank you very much.